# How do i get rid of wrinkles in a subsurf

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, artifacts

I have been modeling a dagger. I've just finished doing the rough profiling. I've added a subsurf modifier to smooth it out a bit but i cannot figure out how to get rid of these wrinkles. can any of you guys help me out? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here's the Blend File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6u1lf41x9vujwd/Dagger.blend?dl=0

Comment: By 'wrinkles', do you mean that you want it to be sharp rather than smooth at certain transitions, or that you have unintended unevenness in the diameter of the mesh cross-section?

Comment: yeah was talking about the uneven-ness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but if your goal is to selectively convert some of the smooth transitions to sharp transitions, you can do this either by adding additional Geometry (often through loop cuts, as shown here):

[image]

(note: sharpness depends on how close the new loop cut is to the old loop cut, because the subdivision surface adds geometry *between* them -- hence, if there is no or little space between them, the subdivision surface has little or nothing to smooth)

Which results in:

[image]

And/or by using Mark Seam: Sharp

[image]

(result not pictured)

If, instead, you want to remove some of the undesired unevenness of the mesh or something else, a different answer/solution will be needed.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I just removed some of the geometry to stop it being so condensed.